# OPC Publisher module does not start on my Ubuntu VM as an edge module

Tags: linux, azure, opc-ua, azure-iot-edge

The OPC Publisher marketplace image runs successfully as a standalone container (albeit with server connection problems). But I am not able to deploy it as an edge module, especially after changing container create options.

*Background: In my host laptop I was never able to get the module up so I created a Ubuntu VM. When I tried to deploy the edge module in the VM with default container create options the module did show up in the iotedge module list as "running". I wanted to set the "--op" option to set publishing rate so I changed it in the create options using the portal "Set modules" tab. Since there is no update button I used create button to "recreate" the modules. After this the module did not show up.*

After that the OPC publisher module is not showing up on the edge VM. I am following the [Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/industrial-iot/tutorial-publisher-deploy-opc-publisher-standalone).

Following is the command:

```
sudo docker run -v /iiotedge:/appdata mcr.microsoft.com/iotedge/opc-publisher:latest --aa --pf=/appdata/publishednodes.json --c="HostName=<iot hub name>.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey=<hub primary key>" --dc="HostName=<edge device id/name>.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=<edge device id/name>;SharedAccessKey=<edge primary key>" --op=10000
```

Container create options:

```
{
    "Hostname": "opcpublisher",
    "Cmd": [
        "--pf=/appdata/publishednodes.json",
        "--aa",
        "--op=10000"
    ],
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": [
            "/iiotedge:/appdata"
        ]
    }
}
```

I have not specified the connection strings explicitly since the documentation [from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/industrial-iot/tutorial-publisher-configure-opc-publisher) assures that the runtime will pass them automatically.

The relevant iotedge journalctl logs are here.

```
Oct 06 19:36:05 shreesha-VirtualBox iotedged[9622]: 2021-10-06T14:06:05Z [INFO] - Pulling image mcr.microsoft.com/iotedge/opc-publisher:latest...
Oct 06 19:36:08 shreesha-VirtualBox iotedged[9622]: 2021-10-06T14:06:08Z [INFO] - Successfully pulled image mcr.microsoft.com/iotedge/opc-publisher:latest
Oct 06 19:36:08 shreesha-VirtualBox iotedged[9622]: 2021-10-06T14:06:08Z [INFO] - Creating module OPCPublisher...
Oct 06 19:36:08 shreesha-VirtualBox iotedged[9622]: 2021-10-06T14:06:08Z [INFO] - Starting new listener for module OPCPublisher
Oct 06 19:36:08 shreesha-VirtualBox iotedged[9622]: 2021-10-06T14:06:08Z [ERR!] - Internal server error: Could not create module OPCPublisher
Oct 06 19:36:08 shreesha-VirtualBox iotedged[9622]:         caused by: Could not get module OPCPublisher
```

The logs from iotedge itself is not much useful. Find below anyway.

```
~$ iotedge logs OPCPublisher
A module runtime error occurred
```

I have also tried docker container prune just to be sure but it did not help.

Also strangely in the Azure portal when I try to restart the module from the troubleshoot page it throws an error "module not found in the current environment"

[image: Azure portal module error]

Can someone please help me out in troubleshooting this problem? I will be glad to share more details if required.

Comment: Can you try selecting a specific docker image for the OS you are running on? docker OPC Publisher are listed [here.](https://mcrflowprodcentralus.data.mcr.microsoft.com/mcrprod/iotedge/opc-publisher?P1=1633950456&P2=1&P3=1&P4=mn6ml6i7iHqpfEOYaibVPbi%2Bl7odBmhnzlI3udVQ6sI%3D&se=2021-10-11T11%3A07%3A36Z&sig=1Cx0gx8se9TTbFitHiIeKgTUZry4VynIIh6yyDw0EXw%3D&sp=r&sr=b&sv=2015-02-21) Can you also confirm what is the IoTEdge version you are running? 1.1 or 1.2?

Comment: See as well the most updated tutorial here: [Microsoft OPC Publisher - Standalone Mode](https://github.com/Azure/Industrial-IoT/blob/main/docs/modules/publisher.md)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I raised a support query in Azure portal. After sending support bundles and trying various suggestions like removing DNS configuration, changing bind path to a non-sudo location etc. the team zeroed in on the edge version mismatch.

After re-reading the documentation I **uninstalled the earlier iotedge package and installed aziot-edge instead** and problem solved!

The team has raised a github issue for public tracking here:

https://github.com/Azure/Industrial-IoT/issues/1425

[@asergaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9401038/asergaz) also pointed to the right direction but did not notice since it came a bit later